# Help me to Install magento on Ubuntu I am getting 500 Error or Admin Redirect .

Tags: magento2, installation, http-error-500, centos, ubuntu

Can somebody help me to install fully magento on unbuntu or centOS also suggest me best practices so for future it will help me . I will appreciate the efforts .

Comment: can you provide us with ubuntu version, php version, php mods, mysql/mariadb version, apache version, the content of your vhost and other things like that.

Comment: There is nothing too difficult in installing Magento 2. You just need to take care of PHP version, MySQL version, required PHP extensions and correct folder permissions.

Comment: PHP 7.0.30-
___________
Php mod
 
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
_______________
Mysql 5.7.22
_______________
check this URL 
https://www.households.pk/magento/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to think about Magento Only configure PHP,Mysql and your web server so you will have ease of running Magento 2.

Here are links

[Installing PHP 7 in Ubuntu && linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7)

Comment: I tried with all methods and once it installed but its problem with admin too many redirects (FYI I also tried browser cache clearing and all other possible fixes . )
than I plan to reinstall it . 
so i have all the settings up just problem is it come 500 error so try to fix that but not getting a solution can you see this URL I activated Error View 
https://www.households.pk/magento/